# VS2019 - Google Play Console error - Failed to sign a app bundle

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, google-play-console

I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.4.1.  I am trying to put a app onto the Google Play Store in internal testing.  My app is being bundle as a aab file.  I am getting a upload failed message:

"You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle with invalid or missing signing information for some of its files. You need to create a valid signed APK or Android App Bundle. Learn more about signing."

I also saw this message which might indicate a bug with VS.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/845978/you-uploaded-an-apk-or-android-app-bundle-with-inv.html?inRegister=true

Now my question is how can you poke around inside the aab file and see if it is properly signed?
Also if it isn't signed...is it possible to sign that aab file and how would you do that?

Comment: App Bundles defer signing APKs to the Google Play Store. Did you opt into app signing by Google Play before uploading the app bundle? You can extract an `.aab` and look for the various certificates (`.der` / `.pem`).

Comment: Yes I did opt into app signing by Google Play before trying to uploading the app bundle.  What application can extract the contents of a .aab file?

Comment: You can rename an `.aab` to `.zip` and extract as you would a zip file.